# Issues with php include in sub domain

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, subdomain

I just uploaded my site but am having issues with sub domain and php include.

First I have a directory `/main/` and all it content are okay in localhost and also when I uploaded online until when I decided to forward `www.main.example` to `main` directory.

Now if I browse it this way `www.main.example` files that I include will not work, and also my css, but I manage to add full site name to my css and js like `www.example.com/css/page.css` and is working. So can someone help me with php path or any htaccess code that can help me fix this?

I tried this to but not working

```
include_once('../_inc/functions.php');
include_once(__DIR__ . '/../_inc/userlocation.php');
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i did no error i don't know why

Comment: Can you post your directory tree?